# How to left-align cases inside an equation?

Tags: equations, align, cases, flalign

I am trying to left-align a `cases` inside an equation, like this:

[image]

and I need it to be inside `equation` because of the number `(16)`.
When I try this:

```latex
\begin{equation} \label{eq:evaluate_metrics}
\begin{align*}
    &\begin{cases}
        TPR=T_P/(T_P+F_N)\\
        FPR=F_P/(F_P+T_N)\\
        ACC=(T_P+T_N)/(T_P+F_N+F_P+T_N)\\
        PRE=T_P/(T_P+F_P)
    \end{cases}
\end{align*}
\end{equation}
```

gives me an error:

> Package amsmath Error: Erroneous nesting of equation
> structures;(amsmath) trying to recover with `aligned'. \end{align*}

How can I make it look like the picture while including the equation number?

Comment: It's wrong to use `align*` inside `equation`. Just remove `\begin{align*}`, `\end{align*}` and also the `&`.

Comment: @egreg I did that, the cases are left-aligned, but the whole thing is in the center.

Comment: That's where it should be, unless you left align *all* equations.

Comment: @egreg I get it. It is not possible to left-align only one equation.

Comment: Yes, but why? I see no reason to. If you really want it, change `equation` into `flalign`, add `& in front of `\begin{cases}` and `&&` after `\end{cases}`. But don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain locally left-aligned equations nesting them inside a `fleqn` environment from `nccmath`. This environment can take the distance from the text left margin at which it starts as an optional argument:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, nccmath}
 \usepackage[upright]{fourier} 
\usepackage[reset, showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{fleqn}
\begin{equation} \label{eq:evaluate_metrics}
    \begin{cases}
        TPR=T_P/(T_P+F_N)\\
        FPR=F_P/(F_P+T_N)\\
        ACC=(T_P+T_N)/(T_P+F_N+F_P+T_N)\\
        PRE=T_P/(T_P+F_P)
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{fleqn}

\begin{fleqn}[1em]
\begin{equation} \label{eq:evaluate_metrics}
    \begin{cases}
        TPR=T_P/(T_P+F_N)\\
        FPR=F_P/(F_P+T_N)\\
        ACC=(T_P+T_N)/(T_P+F_N+F_P+T_N)\\
        PRE=T_P/(T_P+F_P)
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{fleqn}
```

\end{document}
[image]